# Is there a way to select WorkItemLinks with the TFS Java API?

Tags: java, tfs, wiql

I'd like to use the TFS Java API to run WIQL queries on the `workitemlinks`. I know how to fetch WorkItems via the WorkItemClient, but it seems to be missing the functionality to fetch WorkItemLinks.

On the other hand, `client.supportsLinkQueries()` returns `true`. So: Is there a way to run `workitemlinks` queries with the TFS Java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around, I found that you can create a link query and run it like this:

```
WorkItemLinkInfo[] infos = client.createQuery("select * from workitemlinks").runLinkQuery()
```

Seems like they forgot to add the convenience method to the WorkItemClient.